# How to store something other than a string in a file

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

I'm trying to write some code to create a file that will write data about a "character". I've been able to write strings using:

```
f = open('player.txt','w')
f.write("Karatepig")
f.close()
f = open('player.txt','r')
f.read()
```

The issue is, how do I store something other than a string to a file? Can I convert it from a string to a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files can only store strings, so you have to convert other values to strings when writing, and converting them back to original values when reading.

The Python standard library has a [whole section dedicated to data persistence](http://docs.python.org/2/library/persistence.html) that can help make this task easier.

However, for simple types, it is perhaps easiest to use the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to serialize data to a file and read it back again with ease:

```
import json

def write_data(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as outfh:
        json.dump(data, outfh)

def read_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infh:
        json.load(infh)
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't have to keep fruitlessly looking through webpages and old stackoverflow posts to get the answer, as I was doing for at least an hour before I asked.